# Receiving and sending back json data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am sending data from services.js coming in as a json encoded string in the following format to myPhp.php:

```
{"Name":"alpha"}
```

I want to gather this data and send back to the services.js as it came back in json form adding beta to the string as in:

```
{"Name":"alpha beta"}
```

myPhp.php

```
<?php
$a = $_POST[data];
$b = json_decode($a);
$c = $b.Name + "beta";
echo ($c);
?>
```

Comment: You have to `json_encode()` the data again...

Comment: Is your data from `services.js` coming in as a json encoded string, or is it from an ajax post?

Comment: as a json encoded string.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $a = $_POST[data];
    $b = json_decode($a);
    $c = $b['Name'] . " beta";
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($c);
?>
```

Comment: `$b.Name + "beta"` is not php. That is a mashup of php and javascript coding.

Comment: @Sean sorry, fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

The "." notation is not used in PHP to access / set properties - more like Javascript and you need to have quotes around the `$_POST` variable ~ unless `data` is defined as a constant. I think you could try something like this though.

```
<?php
    $b = json_decode( $_POST['data'],true );
    $b['name'].='beta';
    echo json_encode($b);
?>
```

Comment: Should also have a `header('Content-type: application/json');` at the top (and if one is really being pedantic, one should also check the client accepts this mimetype or return a 415 error)